# Drupal7 content page load by Jquery

Tags: jquery, drupal

I am new in Drupal, I want to know if there is any way to load the content of nodes(content page,article ) by Javascript ?
here is part of my code :

```
$('#selectedBox li').click(function(){
            var link = $(this);
            var context = link.attr('data-context');                
            $('.selectedBoxContent').html(getContentTab(context));
        });
```

getContentTab returns the related content which is in html format in the .js file , but I want to put it in content page and load it from drupal ? any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot load content via javascript with the standard Drupal installation, but you can use contributed modules to expose Drupal's content via a REST API that outputs JSON.

The most popular module for doing this is [the Services module](https://drupal.org/project/services). I've also heard good things about [Restws](https://drupal.org/project/restws).

To get a sense of what it would take to expose content via REST, [here's an example](http://pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-drupal-7-restful-services) of how you can set it up with Services.